# ANSI escape sequence save/restore cursor position support

Tags: terminal, ansi-escape

Are there any known terminals which support the ANSI escape sequences for cursor keys up, down, forward and back:

```
CSI n A     Cursor Up
CSI n B     Cursor Down
CSI n C     Cursor Forward
CSI n D     Cursor Back
```

but don't support the save-cursor-position and restore-cursor-position escape sequences?

```
CSI s       Save Cursor Position
CSI u       Restore Cursor Position
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A genuine VT100 (or VT220 for that matter) did not recognize these control sequences for save/restore cursor position.  They use (as noted in xterm's [control sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Controls-beginning-with-ESC) list)

```
ESC 7     Save Cursor (DECSC).
ESC 8     Restore Cursor (DECRC).
```

Those are the `sc` and `rc` capabilities in terminfo; you may see these listed using

```
infocmp vt100
infocmp vt220
```

The origin of `CSI s` and `CSI u` likely is from `ansi.sys` (see terminal database entry for [ansi.sys-old](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-ansi_sys-old)), though an older source is always possible.

Comment: It seems to be safer to use `ESC 7` and `ESC 8`. The `CSI s` and `CSI u` sequences are recognised by iTerm 2 but not by Terminal.app on macOS. Similarly, 
[asciinema](https://asciinema.org/) doesn't recognise them when recording.

Comment: What if there is some text printed after `ESC 7` or after `ESC 8`? Some characters seem to confuse the terminal into thinking that the `7` is actually an argument to a completely different command :P (e.g. if you send `\033[7Hello` it actually moves the cursor to the 7th column and prints `ello` there because the initial `H` is the "move cursor" command. Is there any way to terminate the escape sequence after the `7` so that the text that follows wouldn't be interpreter as commands?

Comment: `ESC 7` is different from `ESC [ 7`, because the latter (first two characters) is standardized while the former is terminal-dependent.  Any control-character after the second will terminate the sequence (on a standard-compliant terminal, at any rate).

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that there's two of them! :o  And indeed `ESC 7` works for me. It would be nice though that the other one (the "standardized" one, as you said) worked as well. Is there any control character that would terminate the sequence without messing with the output? (some sort of "do nothing" escape sequence)