# Pascal - Clearing terminal

Tags: terminal, pascal, macos-sierra

Getting started with Pascal here. I wanted to write a simple program that first clears the terminal window and then reads user input. The first result of searching for clearing the screen showed the `ClrScr` procedure. Using it gets the job done but `ClrScr` needs `Crt` which results in a new problem. Terminating the program using `Ctrl + C` does not work. Searching online again, I found that `Crt` takes over I/O. I have been looking for alternative to `ClrScr` but haven't really found anything so far.

> So how can I clear terminal while still being able to terminate the program using `Ctrl + C`. Also how can I terminate the program in the current case using `Crt`?

Current Code:

```
    program Test;
    uses Crt;
    var     
            x : integer;
    begin
            read(x);
    end.
```

Comment: What operating system are you using? Linux and Windows have a command to clear the screen, so you could make a system call to that command. The other option, while using `Crt`, is to catch `Ctrl+C` by reading it as a key and acting on it explicitly.

Comment: @lurker macOS sierra

Comment: You will have to explicitly read `^C` as a key (using `KeyPressed`, `ReadKey`) at appropriate places and react to it. On Windows, there is a [`SysSetCtrlBreakHandler`](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/syssetctrlbreakhandler.html), but I don't know if that exists on other platforms.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis So far, reading `^C` seems the only way to do it and something that I don't feel like implementing. Might just discard `Crt` from the code totally.

Comment: Yes, discarding Crt is not such a problem. If you need coloured text or something like ClrScr, simply use the appropriate OS routines, or use  escape sequences (IIRC, [that should work on the Mac too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879183/can-terminal-app-be-made-to-respect-ansi-escape-codes)).

Comment: I sometimes used to write enough blank lines to the screen to make the text scroll off.

Comment: @Stuart Might work but will also need to edit cursor position which can be troublesome at times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far the solutions I have seen online and the ones suggested in the comments for keeping `CRT` just make it troublesome and unnecessary makes the program complex. So for now I have decided just to discard it totally.

The workaround I have found now is to use `unix.fpsystem` with the `clear` command which gets the job done just fine.